# ActiveAdmin breaks Rails JQuery UJS. Unobtrusive JavaScript ajax:success and ajax:error are not firing or being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-ujs

I have the following

```
=form_for @issue, remote: true, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f|
  ...
```

And

```
<form class="form-inline" id="new_issue" action="/issues" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

And

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $("#new_issue").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log 'data='+data
    console.log 'status='+status
    console.log 'xhr='+xhr
    $("#new_issue_success").append(xhr.responseText).show()
    $("#new_issue_error").hide()
  ).on("ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log 'error='+error
    console.log 'status='+status
    console.log 'xhr='+xhr
    $("#new_issue_error").append("ERROR: #{error}").show()
    $("#new_issue_success").hide()
  ).on('ajax:complete', ->
    console.log 'complete'
  )
```

And

```
  def create
    issue = Issue.new issue_params
    issue.validate_user_entry
    if issue.errors.empty? && issue.save # can't use #valid? because that clears errors and runs only standard Rails validations!
      render json: issue, status: :created
    else
      render json: issue.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
```

I get this in my browser console

```
POST http://localhost:3000/issues 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/issues".
```

And this in my Rails server console

```
Started POST "/issues" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-07 22:29:34 -0400
Processing by IssuesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "issue"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "city"=>"", "issue"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So why isn't it calling the Ajax callback and printing out the results on the console? Whether it succeeds or fails, I expected it to show the results.

It's taken straight from the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for

I also tried

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  ...
).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
  ...
```

I verified the event is listening on the element in the browser

[image]

I have something almost exactly like this in another Rails project that works. I downgraded to Rails 5.0.6 like the other project but it didn't help.

Rails 5.0.7, JQuery 3.3.1

---

I've discovered this is caused by ActiveAdmin. I have [entered a bug for it](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5425). When I rename `active_admin.js.coffee` to `active_admin.js.coffee.xxx` then it works, but of course breaks ActiveAdmin then. I tried adding `//= stub active_admin` to `application.js`, but for some reason `jquery_ujs` would not load. I viewed the source of the page and `/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784...` would no longer appear, despite `//= require jquery_ujs` being in `application.js`.

How can I have both ActiveAdmin and UJS? I don't need UJS on `/admin` pages.

Comment: did you try moving ajax callbacks outside of `turbolink:load` callback?

Comment: @kasperite Yes. See 'I also tried...'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by moving `active_admin.js.coffee` to `vendor\assets\javascripts\active_admin.js.coffee`. Now the `/admin` works and the remote form at `/` works. Not obvious at all. Wish they put this in the docs, or better yet, just not interfere with standard Rails.

Comment: doesn't worked for me sadly...
Do you have any idea on why this happened?